# Where should I put question marks when a sentence is split in a bulleted list?

Tags: puntuación

Although it is not strictly grammatically correct, in English it is common to have bulleted lists of questions with the same noun phrase omitted from the list and put before it.
An example is as follows:
How often do you ...

- Brush your teeth?
- Floss your teeth?
- Use mouthwash?

This makes it easier to read, as repeating the noun phrase clutters the page. (The items are capitalized to make them more legible.)

In Spanish where should I put question marks?

Is the following correct?
Con qué frecuencia…
• ¿Cepillarse los dientes?
• ¿Usa hilo dental?

Comment: What noun phrase? Do you mean the helping verb **did** and pronoun **you**? There is nothing

Answer (score 5):

No encontré ninguna regla muy oficial que digamos. Pero de acuerdo a lo que decís y usando teoría de árboles, lo que tenemos es una oración que comienza en *How often* (es el nodo raíz) y luego se bifurca en tres nodos distintos, que son los que la terminan. Por otra parte, la pregunta comienza y termina exactamente cuando comienza y termina la oración respectivamente. Por lo que lo correcto sería:

> ¿Qué tan seguido...
>
> - te cepillás los dientes?
> - usás hilo dental?
> - usás enjuague bucal?

Y es cierto que, aunque se entiende perfectamente, este tipo de estilo parece más propio de una campaña de marketing. En documentos formales—un formulario, por ejemplo—se prefiere evitar interrumpir la pregunta con una lista, por lo que nos quedarían dos opciones:

O cerramos la pregunta antes de la lista,

> ¿Con qué frecuencia suele realizar las siguientes rutinas?
>
> - Cepillarse los dientes:
> - Usar hilo dental:
> - Usar enjuague bucal:

o recurrimos al estilo indirecto.

> Indique con qué frecuencia suele realizar las siguientes rutinas:
>
> - Cepillarse los dientes:
> - Usar hilo dental:
> - Usar enjuague bucal: